# Как узнать, что анимация закончилась?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity, C#. Есть модель с animator, в котором уже настроены стейты-анимации и параметры для переходов между ними.

Мне нужно проигрывать анимации в определенном порядке. Чтобы вызвать нужную анимацию мне достаточно чекнуть нужный параметр:

```
GetComponent.<Animator>().SetBool("someparameter",true);
```

Как написать условие "когда текущая анимация закончится"?
Все варианты что нахожу, либо про `Animation`, а не `Animator`, либо слишком сложны, а нужен простой способ в котором можно быстро разобраться и   использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `Animator` есть метод **[GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.html)**, который получает информацию о текущем состоянии на указанном слое Контроллера Аниматора (AnimatorController). То есть он возвращает **[AnimatorStateInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html)** Вот им и стоит воспользоваться.

У `AnimatorStateInfo`, в свою очередь, есть поле `IsName` - которое говорит, совпадает ли `name` с именем активного состояния в `statemachine`. В итоге может получится что-то такое:

```
private Animator animator;

private void Start() {
    animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();        
}

public bool IsAnimationPlaying(string animationName) {        
    // берем информацию о состоянии
    var animatorStateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    // смотрим, есть ли в нем имя какой-то анимации, то возвращаем true
    if (animatorStateInfo.IsName(animationName))             
        return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

Как применение - нужно указать имя слоя, точку, имя анимации:

```
if (IsAnimationPlaying("Base Layer.Run"))
    Debug.Log("Player is running");
```

Для проверки нескольких анимаций скорее всего придется их поместить в массив и пробегаться циклом:

```
foreach (var move in attackMoves) {
    if (IsAnimationPlaying(move.animationName)) {                   
        // do smth...
    }
}
```

P.S. `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` - получает информацию на определенном слое.  Поэтому чтобы взять инфу на самом базовом слое стоит `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0)`. В других слоях индекс будет меняться естественно.

Comment: Огромое вам спасибо? то что нужно!

Answer (score 6):

Не очень понятно что вы хотите, если после того как одна анимация закончилась вы хотите перейти в другую так настройте переходы между стейтами в `Mecanim`.

Если вам нужно отловить сам момент когда делается выход из состояния можно воспользоваться классами [StateMachineBehaivour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) который как раз умеет реагировать на работу в состояние. Этот скрипт навешивается в Mecanim на само состояние. В окне аниматора выбираете требуемое состояние и для него в окне инспектора добавить соответствующий скрипт, как это делается с компонентами на сцене.

Comment: Огромно спсибо, попробую и этот способ!